# How to use user-specified theme in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I've been trying to theme my react-navigation navigators, which was easy with hard coded colours i.e. `Colours.background`, `Colours.accent`.

When a user is authenticated I supply their basic details, and a theme object. This gets stored in my app state using redux (`state.auth.user.theme`)

I have an AppNavigation where my navigators are created.

### AppNavigation.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, Animated, Easing, Image, View } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import DrawerContainer from '../Containers/DrawerContainer'
import ScreenTwoScreen from '../Containers/ScreenTwoScreen'
import ScreenOneScreen from '../Containers/ScreenOneScreen'
import DashboardScreen from '../Containers/DashboardScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../Containers/LoginScreen'

import styles from './Styles/NavigationStyles'
import ThemeProvider from '../Themes/ThemeProvider';
import Images from '../Themes/Images';

const Colors = ThemeProvider()

const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  screenOneScreen: { screen: ScreenOneScreen },
  dashboardScreen: { screen: DashboardScreen },
}, {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    contentComponent: DrawerContainer
  })

const drawerButton = (navigation) =>
    <Text
      style={{ padding: 5, color: 'white' }}
      onPress={() => {
        // Coming soon: navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')
        // https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2492
        if (navigation.state.index === 0) {
          navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
        } else {
          navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')
        }
      }
      }><Icon name="navicon" color={Colors.headerText} size={24} /></Text>


// login stack
const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  loginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
    }
  })

const logoStyle = {
  height: 45,
  width: 45,
  marginLeft: 10,
  resizeMode: 'contain'
}
const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
  DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.brand },
      title: 'Welcome!',
      headerTintColor: Colors.headerText,
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerRight: drawerButton(navigation),
      headerLeft: <Image source={Images.clubLogo} style={logoStyle} />
    })
  })


// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  loginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
  drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'loginStack',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: styles.header
    }
  })

export default PrimaryNav
```

This gets used in ReduxNavigation.js:

### ReduxNavigation.js

```
import React from 'react'
import * as ReactNavigation from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'
import Colors from '../Themes/Colors'
import ThemeProvider from '../Themes/ThemeProvider'
// here is our redux-aware our smart component
class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
    console.log(navigation)
    return {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: this.props.user ? this.props.user.club.brand : Colors.brand
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav, user } = this.props
    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav
    })


    // if (user) {
    //   theme = ThemeProvider(user.club.theme)
    // }
    return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav, user: state.auth.user })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

### ThemeProvider.js

Nothing fancy:

```
import Colors from './Colors';

const ThemeProvider = (other ={}) => {
    return Object.assign({}, Colors, other)
}

export default ThemeProvider;
```

### Things I've tried

- Created a theme provider method that merges the user theme into colours, it worked but it wasn't right.
- Moved the core of AppNavigation into the render method of ReduxNavigation but that made the app unresponsive, understandably.
- Tried to figure out a way of passing the theme as props to PrimaryNav, react-navigation doesn't like additional props.

Thoughts and ideas? Also, the core of the app was generated with [InfiniteRed/ignite](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) if that's any use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a way, using `screenProps` in ReduxNavigation:

```
class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav, user } = this.props
    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav
    })
    return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} screenProps={{ user }} />
  }

}
```

Then in AppNavigation on the navigators where I need custom themes I do:

```
DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
  DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
      let headerText = Colors.headerText;
      let brand = Colors.brand;
      let accent = Colors.accent;
      if (screenProps.user) {
        let theme = screenProps.user.club.theme;
        brand = theme.brand;
        headerText = theme.headerText;
        accent = theme.accent;
      }
      return ({
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: brand },
        title: 'Welcome!',
        headerTintColor: headerText,
        gesturesEnabled: false,
        headerRight: drawerButton(navigation, headerText),
        headerLeft: <Image source={Images.clubLogo} style={logoStyle} />
      })
    }
  })
```